# Can´t Post JSON to server Express js using OkHttp3 in Android

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm doing some tests using data to register a new user into my DB sending a json by post. The server returns a static string just for testing. I'm getting the proper response using the console and CURL

```
curl --data ''  http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/user/register

 <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Express</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Express</h1><p>Welcome to Express</p></body></html>
```

and even with the POSTMAN extension sending a post request to that same URL I'm getting a proper response as well. But the code below is not getting any response from the server. What's missing?. It's not throwing any error and the json is correct after checking the debugger(it shouldn't matter but just in case anyone wants to know), just a regular string. The debugger fails on this line

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();



private void createUser(String name, String email, String password){

        //create JSON

         final String userJson = formatUserAsJSON(name,email,password);

        //send JSON

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                try {
                  //1.create client Object
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                 //2.Define request being sent to server
                RequestBody postData=new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("json",userJson)
                        .build();

                Request request=new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/user/register")
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();

                //3.Transport the request and wait for response to process next

                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String result = response.body().string();
                    return result;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("error_connection","couldn't connect to the API");
                    return null;
                }


            }

       }.execute();



    }
```

I would appreciate some feedback on this problem. Thank you very much

EDIT: The server is not giving any response cause it's not being reached by the android app. I'm seeing in the ubuntu console and nodejs is not printing any message of any request.....

EDIT 2: In the Android manifest I have the user permission to access the network so it's not that.....

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Try to Log the response you're getting, print that here, and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem putting the network IP(it also works if you put the Public internet IP, I've tried it) of the server cause 127.0.0.1 was refering to the Genymotion emulator itself, silly me :S. But that was the answer. Thanks everyone for their support.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your JSON inside a FormBody

try this:

```
RequestBody postData = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), userJson);
```

Comment: I tried this without any luck...There's still not any requests on the server console......I run the debugger and the request content is this

`Request{method=POST, url=http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/user/register, tag=null}`

.The json format is correct as well

Comment: I was thinking the problem might be the use of 127.0.0.1. It should be the public IP right?.....cause I think 127.0.0.1 refers to the emulator itself(Genymotion in this case). I will try that and post the answer if it's correct.....